# Checkboxes not getting clicked

Tags: android, checkbox

I am working on self-learning android and presently trying my hands on creating a list view with checkboxes. However when I run the program and I do see the list view with checkboxes, but I don't see checks in the checkbox when I select any of the options. Am I missing something here?

***MainActivity:***

```
package com.example.practisetutorials.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        String[] fruits = {"Banana", "Mango", "Apple", "Guava", "Orange", "Water Melon", "Grapes", "Cantaloupe", "Strawberry", "Blackberry", "Blueberry", "Papaya", "Pineapple"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.fruit_item, R.id.checkedTextView, fruits);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }
}
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.practisetutorials.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

***fruit_item.xml***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckedTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:checkMark="@color/accent_material_light"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these lines below listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); in onCreate() method.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);
            if(checkedTextView.isChecked()) {
                checkedTextView.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This worked for me. I tried removing setChecked and thought just setting onItemClickListener would allow me to select the items. But looks like since it's CheckedTextView, I also need to add setChecked along with the onItemClickListener to select the options in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `setOnItemClickListener`

Take a look here : http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes.php

Comment: Thanks shank! I was under impression that onItemClickListener is needed only when I want to perform some actions like maybe displaying a Toast after the selections are made. I thought that since it's a checkbox, I should be able to check it without setting any listener. But looks like maybe it's not the case with CheckedTextView.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you're trying to use the CheckedTextView?  I usually just use CheckBox.  It works out of the box.  Here's how to do it without modifying your code too much:

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.test;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Context context;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    String[] fruits = {"Banana", "Mango", "Apple", "Guava", "Orange", "Water Melon", "Grapes", "Cantaloupe", "Strawberry", "Blackberry", "Blueberry", "Papaya", "Pineapple"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.fruit_item, R.id.checkedTextView, fruits);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
//        listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
//        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }
}
```

Then fruit_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:checkMark="@color/accent_material_light"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Martin_xs6! I will try this out. I am learning android and have a project in my mind. So just learning and practicing in pieces right now. While reading some stuff I came across CheckedTextView and was trying my hands on it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you're missing a click listener on your listview. Add this at the bottom of your onCreate:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You tapped: " +fruits[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

and declare your String[] as final so you can access it inside your click listener.

Comment: setting onItemClickListener works. Thanks seanAshmore!